# How can I connect Instagram videos on my web site?

Tags: php, css, web, instagram

I want to deploy my 5 most recent instagram videos on a layout
How can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instagram already has a pretty good documentation on this. https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

Just try to read through it, I think that it will help you.

Comment: An answer should stand on it's own. What happens if the link dies?